# Calculating a period as long as a criteria is met in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is my dataframe:

```
                            date       value  negative  trigger period
125652 2020-01-12 07:00:00+00:00   21.688670     False    False    NaN
125653 2020-01-12 07:05:00+00:00    1.456942     False    False    NaN
125654 2020-01-12 07:10:00+00:00  -22.268280      True    False      1
125655 2020-01-12 07:15:00+00:00  -37.850510      True    False      2
125656 2020-01-12 07:20:00+00:00  -66.259944      True    False      3
125657 2020-01-12 07:25:00+00:00  -68.059245      True    False      4
125658 2020-01-12 07:30:00+00:00  -63.986797      True    False      5
125659 2020-01-12 07:35:00+00:00  -75.223634      True    False      6
125660 2020-01-12 07:40:00+00:00  -73.597524      True    False      7
125661 2020-01-12 07:45:00+00:00  -68.174247      True    False      8
125662 2020-01-12 07:50:00+00:00  -80.020121      True    False      9
125663 2020-01-12 07:55:00+00:00  -84.121360      True    False     10
125664 2020-01-12 08:00:00+00:00  -98.860264      True    False     11
125665 2020-01-12 08:05:00+00:00 -120.808291      True     True     12
125666 2020-01-12 08:10:00+00:00 -100.162919      True    False     13
125667 2020-01-12 08:15:00+00:00  -80.048591      True    False     14
125668 2020-01-12 08:20:00+00:00  -23.830259      True    False     15
125669 2020-01-12 08:25:00+00:00    8.356292     False    False     NaN
125670 2020-01-12 08:30:00+00:00   95.368355     False    False     NaN
125671 2020-01-12 08:35:00+00:00   79.023180     False    False     NaN
125672 2020-01-12 08:40:00+00:00   72.057324     False    False     NaN
125673 2020-01-12 08:45:00+00:00   35.903934     False    False     NaN
```

The column `period` is what i want. So basically, i want to count the rows with negative values as long as they are negative. To be more precise: I only need the period when `trigger === True`. I don't care about the period in other rows. So i need `period` on row with index `125665` which is `12` in the example

The initial dataframe doesn't have the column `period`.

I wasn't able to create an algo which can calculate this column for me.
I tried working with `for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():` but this takes ages to iterate over all the rows (check the index of the dataframe cutout).

Does anybody know an fast algo which gives me the period column with a valid period when `trigger == True` ?

Comment: Is the counter supposed to be reset for each period?

Comment: Yes. When "trigger === true" i want to know who many values were negative in a row.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can identify the groups of continuous positive/negative values with this:

```py
df['grp'] = df.negative.diff().cumsum().fillna(0)
```

I explained the reasoning behind this neat little trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66209794/getting-local-max-min-values-from-variable-row-ranges-defined-with-a-condition/66210963#66210963), feel free to check it out if you want to understand the logic behind it

With the groups identified, you can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and cumulative summation on the `negative` column to get the count of negative values in the current group

```py
df['period'] = df2.groupby('grp').negative.cumsum()
```

Because `df.negative` is always `False` for groups of positive values, `period` will be zero for these rows and you can use `df.period.replace({0: np.nan})` to set them to null to achieve your described outcome. If you won't ever touch these values anyway, I recommend simply leaving them at zero to save on computation time